# how to partially match between 2 columns in R

Tags: r, sql-update, matching, partials, startswith

I'm having trouble finding out if values partially match between 2 columns in different tables so i could update values accordingly. The problem is trying to match a longer value with smaller value and having multiple prefix values. I don't want to use any loops as my dataset is in the 1m range.

df1:

| PRODUCT_8 | VAT |
| --- | --- |
| 72093234 | 0,2 |
| 30023000 | 0,2 |
| 12093236 | 0,2 |
| 30066012 | 0,2 |

df2:

| KN |
| --- |
| 30022000 |
| 30023000 |
| 300660 |
| 72 |

Desired output:

| PRODUCT_8 | VAT |
| --- | --- |
| 72093234 | 0,9 |
| 30023000 | 0,9 |
| 12093236 | 0,2 |
| 30066012 | 0,9 |

I have tried this:

```r
df1[is.na(pmatch(df1$PRODUCT_8, df2$KN, duplicates.ok = TRUE)) == FALSE, 
                 "VAT"] <- 0.09
```

but `pmatch` doesn't understand if I want to match longer numbers with smaller. It would be perfect if I could just use `startswith(df1$PRODUCT_8, df2$KN)`, but sadly you can't have multiple values in the prefix argument. sqldf is not complying with my demands either, don't know what's the problem with that.

Comment: You can use `str_detect()` function from `stringr` package for example. `str_detect(string = df1$PRODUCT_8, pattern = paste(df2$KN, collapse = "|"))` gives you logical result TRUE/FALSE. In a tidy form, you can create a new column based on `str_detect`, then update VAT column, as:
`df1 %>% mutate(is_matching = str_detect(string = PRODUCT_8, pattern = paste(df2$KN, collapse = "|"))) %>% mutate(VAT = if_else(condition = is_matching == TRUE, 0.9, VAT))`

Comment: Looks like an ordinary merge, although the data and the answer do not look compatible.

Comment: I thought the goal was to find out whether or not Product_8 and KN columns match, even if only partially, and then to update VAT. But I maybe misunderstood the question... and it is quite probable that the same thing can be done in a much more concise way! :)

Comment: @JGr that's exactly what i want. i'm gonna try out your suggestion, ty